# Length of path between 2 nodes in defined grid [Prolog]

Tags: recursion, prolog

```
edge(a, b).
edge(b, d).
edge(d, c).
edge(d, e).
edge(d, f).
edge(e, g).
edge(f, g).
edge(g, h).
```

(assuming every edge is the same length).

For example, to get the length of the path between a and d:
`?- length(a,d)`
should return `2*constant (a->b and b->d)`.

I know to do a recursive procedure, which I have started called `isConnected` to test if there is a connection between two nodes:

```
isConnected(X1, X2) :- edge(X1, X2).
```

and

```
isConnected(X1, X2) :- edge(X1, X), isConnected(X, X2).
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know I should have a `dist` procedure that calls `isConnected` and and's that result with moving to the next edge, then adding the results with something like `L is Length`. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Daniel is ok, you just apply length/2 to returned list.
Here a more direct way, adding unit steps after the path has been established:

```
isConnected(X1, X2, 1) :- edge(X1, X2).
isConnected(X1, X2, D) :- edge(X1, X), isConnected(X, X2, T), D is T + 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you're actually *really* close! You are even generating all the information you need, you're just not keeping it anywhere. I mean `X` in your second `isConnected/2` rule: that's all you need to retain to get the rest of the way there.

```
isConnected(X1, X2, [X2])      :- edge(X1, X2).
isConnected(X1, X2, [X |Rest]) :- edge(X1, X),  isConnected(X, X2, Rest).
```

That's basically it:

```
?- isConnected(a,X,P).
X = b,
P = [b] ;
X = d,
P = [b, d] ;
X = c,
P = [b, d, c] ;
X = e,
P = [b, d, e] ;
X = f,
P = [b, d, f] ;
X = g,
P = [b, d, e, g] ;
X = h,
P = [b, d, e, g, h] ;
X = g,
P = [b, d, f, g] ;
X = h,
P = [b, d, f, g, h] ;
false.
```